# Javascript - seeing all javascript loaded

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a line like this on a HTML page:

```
<script src="/script/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and suppose the server is not allowing me to load myscript.js directly from the browser.

Is there a way to see the javascript code inside this script from within the browser?

thanks.

Comment: With a debugger? The data has to be downloaded to be executed so it exists somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools/Developer Tools in Chrome.  Select the Scripts tab.

[image]

Firebug in Firefox (this is an extension you have to add).

[image]

F12 or Tools/Developer Tools in Internet Explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If Firefox, VIEW SOURCE, then click on the .js file you see highlighted in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Web Developer tools in Chrome/FF to view the contents of scripts that are loaded for the current page.

Answer (score 0):

just type it in your address bar `http://example.com/script/myscript.js` (of course replacing example.com with whatever the rest of the path is).